# I accidentally sent ERC20 tokens to my Ledger Live wallet, which does not support them. How do I get the tokens out?

Tags: erc-20, wallets, myetherwallet, ledger-nano-s

The Ledger Live wallet does not support ERC 20 tokens.

How do I see and remove ERC20 tokens accidentally sent to a Ledger Live wallet address?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use MyEtherWallet or MyCrypto with the Ledger device to see and manage the ERC20 tokens.

1. Go to "Edit Account" -> Advanced Logs in the Ledger Live wallet.
2. Get the "FreshAddressPath" value.
3. Log onto MyEtherWallet On the "Select Derivation Path" popup, chose
   "Your Custom Path"
4. Type in the value you saved from the ledger live wallet.  It should look something like:  "m/44'/60'/0'/0"  (Note there may be an extra "/0" that needs to be removed.)
5. Find your address in the list

If the token you want to manage is not supported by MyEtherWallet, you can access your account on MyEtherWallet and choose "Add Custom Token" on with this information related to the token: Contract address, Token Symbol, and its decimals.

Answer (score 0):

can you be more specific. I have done the same mistake and can not follow your description.

I'm stuck at point 3. Should I click "create a new Wallet" or "open my wallet" on MEW? (I do not own a wallet on MEW)? Where do I find the "Select Derivation Path"- popup"?

thx

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. I suggest use Add a comment button if you want the author to notice you have a discussion related to his or her answer.